# Escape issue in GITHUB_ENV with quote and ampersand

Tags: bash, terraform, github-actions

I am getting an error when attempting to print github environment value which contains quote and ampersand. Here's how the workflow looks like:

```yaml
name: "Repro"
...

jobs:
  repro:
    runs-on: ubuntu-20.04
    steps:
    - name: "Define multi line variables"
      run: | 
        msg=$(echo 'Terraform used the selected providers to generate the following execution plan.
        Resource actions are indicated with the following symbols:
        ~ update in-place

        Terraform will perform the following actions:
        
        # module.app.helm_release.repro will be updated in-place
        ~ resource helm_release repro {
              id                         = repro
              name                       = repro
            ~ values                     = [
                  <<-EOT
                      ok: contains&character
                      ok2: "something-quoted"
                      problem: "aloha&barnie"
                      # ISSUE: anything after aloha is truncated when put to GITHUB_ENV, including this comment!
        ... (should not be truncated)
        ')
        echo "this is still good, not truncated: $msg"
        echo "SOME_ENV_VAR<<EOF" >> $GITHUB_ENV
        echo "$msg" >> $GITHUB_ENV
        echo "EOF" >> $GITHUB_ENV

    - name: "Try to print SOME_ENV_VAR with CAT - OK"
      run: | 
        echo `cat <<EOF
          ${{ env.SOME_ENV_VAR }}
        EOF`

    - name: "Try to print SOME_ENV_VAR without CAT/EOF - NOT OK"
      run: | 
        echo "${{ env.SOME_ENV_VAR }}"
```

[image: github_error_screenshot]

```
line 17: $'barnie\n              # ISSUE: anything after aloha is truncated when put to GITHUB_ENV, including this comment!\n... (should not be truncated)': command not found
```

So this issue happens with the `echo "${{ env.SOME_ENV_VAR }}"` command. Why is that when I have a quote on its own that's OK, ampersand on its own that's OK, but seemingly not both in the same line?

**Possible solution...**

I am able to print the value using CAT EOF like the following:

```bash
echo `cat <<EOF
  ${{ env.SOME_ENV_VAR }}
EOF`
```

**The ask**

I am interested to understand why the combination of quote and ampersand leads to this issue. Furthermore I cannot use CAT EOF solution above as I need to include this ENV variable in subsequent step that cannot execute shell script but can read ENV variable. Any ideas?

````yaml
- name: Inform Terraform Plan Results
  uses: mshick/add-pr-comment@v2
  with:
    repo-token: ${{ secrets.GITHUB_TOKEN }}
    message-id: tf_plan_${{ matrix.environment }}
    message: |
      **Terraform plan for ${{ matrix.environment }}**
      <details>
        <summary>app/repro</summary>

        ```diff
        ${{ env.SOME_ENV_VAR }}
        ```
      </details>
````

Comment: Given the breakpoint behaviour, it almost looks like a missing double-quote somewhere ... **OR** the program calling this is wrapping it with double-quotes, thereby exposing the "**@**" sign to the OS and interpreting it as a kind of buffer flush.   Looked more closely, that is what is happening at ... **echo "$msg" >> $GITHUB_ENV** ... which means that you need to escape the double-quotes to ensure portions of code are not "protruding" out of the echo command's double-quotes.  I would recommend using temporary external file, massaging that as required with sed, then using it to define ENV.

Comment: Yup you are right. Looking closely again I think I can explain what's happening. The first quote marks the end of the echo, `aloha&` is treated as next command but executed in background, and finally whatever comes after it is treated as command hence `command not found` error.

I was considering to store the result in file, but I won't be able to use it in subsequent step with no access to shell command, e.g. cannot do `cat tmp.txt`. I will try to escape the values prior to storing to GITHUB_ENV and hopefully this should be sufficient.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Given the breakpoint behaviour, it almost looks like a missing double-quote somewhere ... **OR** the program calling this is wrapping it with double-quotes, thereby exposing the "**@**" sign to the OS and interpreting it as a kind of buffer flush.

Looked more closely, that is what is happening at ... **echo "$msg" >> $GITHUB_ENV** ... which means that you need to escape the double-quotes to ensure portions of code are not "protruding" out of the echo command's double-quotes. I would recommend using temporary external file, massaging that as required with sed, then using it to define ENV.

Comment: I assumed GITHUB_ENV handles the escaping of quotes when printed in an echo. It seems to handle quotes on its own nicely hence my assumption. Otherwise escaping the quotes prior to storing it in GITHUB_ENV is what I need. Thanks for your help!

Comment: Escaping quotes, and having to do that at multiple levels, becomes VERY messy ... and best avoided.